# Can I open a project created with Xcode 11, with Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Can I open a project created with Xcode 11, with Xcode 9?

If I build the project with Xcode 11, can I open it with Xcode 9 afterwards?

iOS target: 10.0

EDIT:
I saw now this setting in Xcode: is this the answer to my question?

[image]

Comment: You can, but you may have a long run to make it work there.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Is maybe better to download xCode 9.4 on the same machine and use this for a specific project?

Comment: When you work with newer Xcode, you change a lot of things without notice. You can make them all back to original and replace them with the older version, but you need a git to detect witch part changed automatically and need a strong Swift, iOS and Xcode changes history to know what is going to replace manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change **Opens in**  for storyboard

[image]

Then change `swift_version` in build settings from swift 4 ( lowest in xcode 11 ) to 3

Comment: That is for the interface builder/storyboard only

Comment: @Scriptable the others are easy to migrate just change the the swift version

Comment: @Sh_Khan Can I instal both xCodes on the same machine and use xCode 9 then?

Comment: @Sh_Khan xCode app doesn't open. Can xCode 9.4 run on macOS Catalina? I can't find an answer

Comment: @Scriptable what about the Project Document setting (see the screenshot in the question). Is that the setting that makes the project compatible with xCode 9.4?